Virtual Machine from Azure marketplace image with terraform deployment failed error
am getting below error message for the plan block unable to run as expected, Please help,
Reference Unable to get the context , tried several options including publisher and product to be same, 
plan{
  name = "cloude"
  product = "cloudeteer"
  publisher = "cloudeteer"
}

Unable to deploy from the Marketplace image or a custom image sourced from Marketplace image. The part number in the purchase information for VM,is not as expected. Beware that the Plan object's properties are case-sensitive


Hi @cloudcop, The cloude image is a paid image. Before creating a VM with this image, make sure to purchase the offer.

@VenkatV To be  more precise one needs to accept  the agreement terms which I did at the beginning.

Check whether or not the offer has been created, and view the request status.

To avoid more confusion am posting the answer which i should have done on the day i posted my question, the error clearly refers  to use the plan attributes as it is, no modifications terraforming the deployment.
